# WebPartZone by force renders other WebPartZone as child

Tags: web-part-zone

Following is the code to render webpartzone on my sharepoint site, but I'm not getting output as expected. (Sharepoint 2013)

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="wpzone1" data-name="WebPartZone">
            <!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
            <div xmlns:ie="ie">
                <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="x0e5f5212505f48a9aac43df13eeae4f9" AllowCustomization="True" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" LockLayout="True" Orientation="Vertical">-->
                <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
                <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages. -->
                <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
                <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
            </div>
            <!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="aside">
        <div id="wpzone2" data-name="WebPartZone">
            <!--CS: Start Web Part Zone Snippet-->
            <!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
            <div xmlns:ie="ie">
                <!--MS:<WebPartPages:WebPartZone runat="server" ID="x0e5f5212505f48a9aac43df13eeae4f9" AllowCustomization="True" AllowPersonalization="False" FrameType="TitleBarOnly" LockLayout="True" Orientation="Vertical">-->
                <!--MS:<ZoneTemplate>-->
                <!--DC: Replace this comment with default web parts for new pages.-->
                <!--ME:</ZoneTemplate>-->
                <!--ME:</WebPartPages:WebPartZone>-->
            </div>
            <!--CE: End Web Part Zone Snippet-->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Following is how it renders (output), ids wpzone1 and wpzone2 i specified to make it logical here, but i don't have these ids set on real code

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="wpzone1">
            <div id="aside">
                <div id="wpzone2">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```